# Error Handling in C#

Tags: c#, mvvm, error-handling

Because I am writing my first MVVM application and I never write so "big" application. I have no idea how error handling for users is normally done.

I found some "guide":
http://codebuild.blogspot.co.at/2012/01/15-best-practices-about-exception.html

At first point is mentioned: "Don't manage business logic with exceptions. Use conditional statements instead. If a control can be done with if-else statement clearly, don't use exceptions because it reduces readability and performance  (e.g. null control, divide by zero control)."

So is better to use if-else statment? Or how do you do? Or is better only working with try-catch statment?

And later when I have more if-else code statments one in other .. is better to use basic error bool and error string for all over the code? When happend just turning this bool to true state and write message to error string? And later by showing result check if any error happend?

If you dont understand the question please ask, or write how do you handle with errors in code for user?

Any general guide will be welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned exceptions decrease performance (not sure about readability, I personally never had a problem with that). If you compare how long it takes to check something with **IF** statement or with **TRY-CATCH**, you will notice a huge difference in favor of the first one.

I would say use **IF** statement everywhere, where you can check validity yourself - if it fails, in else statement you can specify what needs to be done (display message to user etc.). For example when dividing x/y

```
    private static void IfMethod()
    {
        int x = 10;
        int y = 0;

        if (y != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x / y);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("y is 0");
        }
    }
```

**Try-catch** is more for situations where you can't predict everything. For example if you are trying to read/write a file you will never for 100% know if you have access to that particular file, the file system or if the file actually exist. This is especially true if you are writing applications for someone else. You have no way to know how they configured their PC, access rights etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Just this confirmation I needed. Because I view this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MO3sOTWfZPc) and this guy made same sample program to "complicated". Givin if-else statement inside catch.

Comment: Let's say your `IfMethod` is in a library class called 'Divider', and `x` and `y` are passed in as arguments. If someone calls `Divider.IfMethod(10, 0)` what should the method do in that case? Writing "y is 0" to the console is obviously no good to the caller, unless the caller is capturing the console output. This is *exactly* why exceptions exist, exceptions are a way of signalling the method's caller about an exceptional situation, which the called method isn't equipped to handle.

Comment: @Boris B. I agree. However I my answer is showing what is the general idea with exceptions, not giving a solution to a PARTICULAR problem.

Comment: `If`ing a potential error condition only makes sense if you definitely know what to do in the `else` branch, otherwise an exception should be raised. Handling of it should be left to the caller, which can the choose to either ask the user to correct the input, or log the error and abort, or just assume the result of division is 0 and continue.

Comment: Boris B.: Again, agreed. Hence my answer saying 'for situations where you can't predict everything'. And again as in my previous comment: my answer is not solving particular problem, just explaining the general concept.

Answer (score 1):

> Don't manage business logic with exceptions. Use conditional
>   statements instead. If a control can be done with if-else statement
>   clearly, don't use exceptions because it reduces readability and
>   performance

True. But let's clarify, what is meant here.
This is a sample, when logic is built on exceptions:

```
private int? Foo(int a)
{
    try
    {
        // bar is some int field
        return bar / a;
    }
    catch (DivideByZeroException)
    {
        return null;
    }    
}
```

Here, method `Foo` *expects*, that `a` can be 0. Hence, `a == 0` isn't an *exception*. But, instead of this:

```
private int? Foo(int a)
{
    if (a == 0)
        return null;

    return bar / a;
}
```

the logic of this method uses an exception to detect, that result of the method is undetermined, and returns special value (`null`).

On the other hand, here's sample, when you must use exception:

```
public int Foo(int a)
{
    if (a == 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("a can't be 0!");

    return bar / a;
}
```

This version of `Foo` is a public method from class library. The logic of `Foo` can't handle the case, when `a == 0`. So, it must check input parameter, and throw exception.

To re-phrase citation above:

- do not throw exceptions, if current state can (and must) be handled by your business logic; use conditional statements instead.
- do throw exceptions, if current state is unexpected, and cannot (must not) be handled by your business logic.